# Is data traffic made via WebRTC measured on a platform like Heroku for example?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, video-streaming, webrtc

I want to build a Facetime clone app using NodeJS, ReactJS and WebRTC.
I am new to WebRTC and I don't know how data is transferred between clients.
My question is that if I will deploy the app on a platform like Heroku, the data transferred via video call is measured by Heroku ?  That will mean huge costs to make some realtime video calls

Comment: You will page huge costs when your p2p peers will not be able to establish direct p2p connection and will connect via TURN proxy.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is peer-to-peer so would not use your Heroku data for the audio/video. Just for the matching, signing up, etc. The peers (web browsers) connect to each other and pass data directly.

However, WebRTC can only handle so many connected clients before each client cannot keep up. So a server system that relays the videos or mirrors the video (itself acting as one of the peers) **would** use bandwidth. But for only two videos, peer-to-peer should be ok assuming the client's bandwidth is sufficient.

Comment: That's great! So I can have many peers that can use the app without paying a lot of money to Heroku! Thanks!

Comment: Mind you that you will need TURN servers to get reliable connections. You can't run them on Heroku and they do cost money.

Comment: As @Philipp stated, peer to peer here is best effort at best. So some of the calls (20% or even more of them) will require relaying the video data through TURN servers - which cost money.

Comment: is there any way to avoid using TURN servers in those 20% of the cases ?

Comment: if there was, why would people use them?